# Fastest way to scan a gltexture for a particular color?

Tags: opengl

Say I have a texture sitting in video memory and somewhere hidden inside this texture maybe one or more pixels with a particular color. In c++ I want to call a function on this gltexture to check for the presence of this color and simply return true or false. What is the **fastest** way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the best performance/simplicity ratio would be to keep a copy on the CPU and test each texel, optionnaly with SSE.

You can also do it in OpenGL :

- Create a render target of the same size than your texture
- Do a fullscreen render of your texture in it - that is, each texel will match one fragment of the render target. Disable any fancy texture sampling
- When rendering, use a shader which discards any texel except the one with the wanted color
- Count the number of rendered fragments with an occlusion query.

I'm not sure of the performance of this, but it's likely to by the fastest you'll get on the GPU side. Note that while fast, this method has lag : you usually only get the occlusion query's result 1 or 2 frames later (you can also busy wait, though).

Comment: Not bad. I was not aware of occlusion queries. I'm going to try this out!

Comment: @ChristianRau I don't know about the time needed to fetch an atomic_counter value. I imagine it's about the same that OQs; do you have any number about this ?

Comment: @Calvin1602 No, it just came to my mind after reading the question, since I didn't think of occlusion queries (and I dropped it after reading your answer). But they aren't as widely supported as occlusion queries and I don't have any experience with them either, so I don't know if it would be faster. But well, you always have to wait for the rendering to be finished before fetching anything and I don't know in which way the occlusion query logic is hardwired or implemented more or less just as an atomic counter anyway.

Comment: @Calvin1602 But maybe when querying `GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED` the render/driver can be smart enough to make the query result available once any fragment passed the test.